# Implicit conversions for sealed traits

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to create implicit conversions for case classes. Here's my domain:

```
case class WbProp(name:String,values:WbVal*)
sealed trait WbVal
case class WbLit(value:String) extends WbVal
case class WbRef(obj:String) extends WbVal
```

I want to convert to lift-json objects, so I have:

```
implicit def lit2json(r:WbLit) :JValue = ("@value"->r.value)
implicit def ref2json(r:WbRef) :JValue = ("@id"->r.obj)
implicit def prop2json(p:WbProp):JValue = JField(p.name,p.values)
```

json-lift can convert Seq[A] to JArray if it has a conversion from A->JValue. However, this doesn't work as it stands - it can't convert from WbVal to json, so I have to add:

```
implicit def val2json(v:WbVal) : JValue = v match {
  case l:WbLit => lit2json(l)
  case r:WbRef => ref2json(r)
}
```

I hoped that having a sealed trait and implicit conversions from all the members would be enough. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why not just have `prop2json` and `val2json`?

Comment: While it would be possible to synthesise the implicit `val2json`, it isn't at all obvious why the compiler should do that for you. It is probably a feature too specific to warrant such a compiler extension.

Comment: @PetrPudlák: that's fine for this case, and probably what I'll end up doing, but it seems inelegant

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff: that makes sense. I guess I was just hoping that was part of the magic of sealed traits